# UNIX (Bash): Splitting Strings into variables to be used in text

Tags: bash, unix

I am working on a project in which I need to have portions of a data file read into variables (last name, first name, room, etc) to be displayed in a paragraph, which is then looped until every name is covered.

The datafile is:

```
James,Robert,M,E162K,5101 Evergreen, Dearborn,Mi,48128
Fulton,Brent,M,E162I,5101 Evergreen, Dearborn,Mi,48128
Conner,Marrci,F,P262J,5101 Evergreen, Dearborn,Mi,48128
Conti,Anthony,M,P252F,5101 Evergreen, Dearborn,Mi,48128
```

And it needs to be fed into the following text: Where the variables listed are replaced with the corresponding names:

```
echo "Dear Mr/Mrs. $lastName" >>project2.output
echo "Welcome to Widgets, Inc. $firstName. This letter is to inform you of your assigned office space at
Widgets, Inc. is in the main $building  building. Your office is $room located at 5101 Evergreen,
Dearborn Mi. 48121.
```

I am not sure how to do this so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: using... which language? Unix is an operating system, are you trying to do this in some kind of shell? If so, which one? And if so: any reason you're doing this on the shell rather than a general purpose scripting language like perl, python, or node?

Comment: Given the `echo` statements, I'm guessing you are looking at a shell script, maybe `bash`. In which case, something like `while IFS=, read lname fname initial room address city state zip; do ..... done < input.txt` is probably a good place to start

Answer (score 5):

What about this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS="," read -r firstName lastName Sex building address city state zip; do
    echo -ne "Dear Mr/Mrs. $lastName, \n"
    echo "Welcome to Widgets, Inc. $firstName. This letter is to inform you of your assigned office space at Widgets, Inc. is in the main $building  building. Your office is $room located at $address,$city $state $zip"
done < datafile
```

Comment: should the 'datafile' in 'done < datafile' be the input or output file?

Comment: 'datafile' here is the input file. Its taking the standard in.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I had never heard of the IFS command before. Very useful!

Comment: IFS is a shell variable, not a command. It is controlling how the read command splits the incoming line into fields. When you use `var=value some_command`, you are setting an environment variable for the strict use of some_command without affecting the currently running shell.